# Mysql query to increment rows till the reach end year in the data column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the data in the fist mentioned table image in mysql and i need the output in the mentioned image format in the table number two. Could you please suggest the query for the same. i am trying some work around but not able to get the desired output.

[image]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to images.)

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query. However, note that issues of data display (such as this) are generally best resolved in application code.

Comment: I need this done in the database. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `MySQL` doesn't have recursive functionality, you have to create a table, `Years` for example, and fill it with years range depending on your data (e.g. from 2010 - 2017).

Once `Years` table created, `LEFT JOIN` it to your table

```
declare @tbl as table (
    car varchar(15)
    ,model varchar(15)
    ,startY int
    ,endY int   
)

declare @years as table(year int)

insert into @tbl values ('audi', 'a1', 2012, 2016)

insert into @years values (2010); insert into @years values (2011)
insert into @years values (2012); insert into @years values (2013)
insert into @years values (2014); insert into @years values (2015)
insert into @years values (2016); insert into @years values (2017)

SELECT
    A.car
    ,A.model
    ,B.year as Model2
FROM @tbl A
LEFT JOIN @years B
    ON B.year BETWEEN A.startY AND A.endY
```